# bash, open, sudo, env, ls, su, nano and other COMMANDS NOT FOUND

Tags: macos, terminal

I am running MAC OSX

I was trying to set environmental variables and I think I screwed up my .bashrc .bash_profile

Now I can't open them and make them correct

HELP!!!

Answer (score 27):

In the terminal type

PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

then

export PATH

Then delete the screwed up .bashrc or .bash_profile. Whichever one was edited

Comment: This saved me a lot of stress. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have created .bashrc and .bash_profile in your home directory, and if you really guess that this is the issue, go ahead and remove them. Restart Terminal and check.

Comment: The problem was I didn't know how to remove them without the temrinal but the temrinal commands were not working... After typing what I suggested and removing like you suggested it is working fine